# Get HashMap key by inputting HashMap value not working as expected

Tags: java, oop, hashmap, hashset, keyset

The problem is in the method `getName()`

```
public class Phonebook implements PhonebookInterface {

    private Map<String, Set<String>> phonebook;
    private Map<String, Address> address;

    public Phonebook() {
        this.phonebook = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        this.address = new HashMap<String, Address>();
    }

    @Override
    public void addNumber(String person, String number) {
        if (!this.phonebook.containsKey(person)) {
            this.phonebook.put(person, new HashSet<String>());
        }

        this.phonebook.get(person).add(number);
    }

    @Override
    public void getName(String number) {
        for (String person : this.phonebook.keySet()) {
            if (this.phonebook.get(person).contains(number)) {
                System.out.println(" " + person);
            } else {
                System.out.println("  not found");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getNumber(String person) {
        try {
            for (String n : this.phonebook.get(person)) {
                if (this.phonebook.get(person).size() > 1) {
                    System.out.println(" " + n);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("number: " + n);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("  not found");
        }
    }

    public void addAddress(String person, String street, String city) {
        this.address.put(person, new Address(street, city));
    }

    public void getInfo(String person) {
        if (this.address.containsKey(person)) {
            System.out.println("  address: " + this.address.get(person));

            if (this.phonebook.containsKey(person)) {
                System.out.println("  phone numbers:");
                for (String n : this.phonebook.get(person)) {
                    System.out.println("  " + n);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("  phone number not found");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("  not found");
        }
    }

    public void removeInfo(String person) {
        if (this.address.containsKey(person)) {
            this.address.remove(person);
        } else {
            System.out.println(" not found");
        }
    }
}

public class Address {

    private String street;
    private String city;

    public Address() {
    }

    Address(String street, String city) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return this.street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.street + " " + this.city;
    }

}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Phonebook p = new Phonebook();

        System.out.println("Search for number: ");

        System.out.println("Pekka :");
        p.addNumber("Pekka", "014-1234");
        p.addNumber("Pekka", "015-5344");
        p.getNumber("Pekka");

        System.out.println("Matti :");
        p.addNumber("Matti", "013-4321");
        p.getNumber("Matti");

        System.out.println("\nsearch for a person by phone number: ");

        p.getName("013-4321");
        p.getName("1234567");
    }
}
```

### The expected output is:

Search for number:
Pekka :
014-1234
015-5344
Matti :
number: 013-4321

search for a person by phone number:
 Matti
 not found

### But the output was :

Search for number:
Pekka :
 014-1234
 015-5344
Matti :
number: 013-4321

Search for a person by phone number:
  not found
 Matti
  not found
  not found

Why is the output printing "**not found**" 3 times instead just once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over all the keys of the `Map` and compare the corresponding values to the value you are looking for. When there's no match, you print "not found".

Your `Map` has two keys, so if you are searching for a value present in the `Map`, you'll print the matching key, but you'll also print "not found" for the other key.

If you are searching for a value not present in the `Map`, you'll print "not found" twice (once for each key).

You should only print "not found" after iterating over all the keys:

```
public void getName(String number) {   
    for (String person : this.phonebook.keySet()) {   
        if (this.phonebook.get(person).contains(number)) {   
            System.out.println(" " + person);
            return;
        }    
    }
    System.out.println("  not found"); 
}
```